# "Cannot Find Symbol" error in constructor, and passing ArrayList from class to class

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

ok im having trouble passing arraylists between classes and im geting a nullPointer exception when i take the constructor out of the object creating in the main. i cant get the arraylist around while also being succesfully modified, or filled with the files it checks for in the directory, keep in mind im new at stackOverflow and programming in general, go easy on me please.

this is the main class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class StreamAudio
{

public static TextArea textArea;
public static ArrayList<File> files;

public StreamAudio()
{

    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();      


    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\hunter\\Desktop\\code\\StreamAudio\\Music");     
    File[] allFiles = folder.listFiles();


    if(folder.isDirectory())
    {

        for (File file : allFiles)
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                files.add(file);

            }
        }
    }               

    int count = 0;
    for(File i : files)
    {
        count++;
        textArea.append(files.get(count - 1).getName()+"\n");

    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{   

    MusicGUI gooey = new MusicGUI(ArrayList<File> files);

}
```

}

and this is the GUI class, can i also have some tips on organizing everything, im so messy

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MusicGUI{

public static TextArea textArea;
public static ArrayList<File> files;

public MusicGUI(ArrayList<File> t)
{
    files = t;
}

public MusicGUI()
{   


JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrostMusic");
JButton next = new JButton("Next");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
TextArea textArea = new TextArea("", 15, 80, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
textArea.setEditable(false);

//frame properties
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(650,450);
frame.setBackground(Color.white);



/////////////////////////    MUSIC CODE     /////////////////////////////


    String path = files.get(1).getPath();
    File song = new File(path);

    String name = song.getName();
    name.replace(".mp3", "");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

JLabel label = new JLabel("Now Playing "+name);


//panel properties
panel.setBackground(Color.white);

//play button
JButton play = new JButton("Play");

try
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(song);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    String filename = song.getName();
    Player player = new Player(bis);



    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent jh)
        {

            try
            {

                player.play();

            }catch(Exception e){}   
        }
    });


    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent jk)
        {
            try
            {
                player.close();

            }catch(Exception e){}   

        }
    });

}catch(Exception e){}



panel.add(play);
panel.add(textArea);
panel.add(label);
panel.add(next);

frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

Comment: can you please add the actual error message

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MusicGUI.<init>(MusicGUI.java:43)
        at StreamAudio.main(StreamAudio.java:53)

Comment: that is without the constructor following the creating of the MusicGUI object, with the constructor the program will not compile.

Comment: MusicGUI gooey = new MusicGUI(ArrayList<File> files); pass proper reference.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line in the `StreamAudio` class inside the `main` method

```
MusicGUI gooey = new MusicGUI(ArrayList<File> files);
```

You cannot "declare" a variable inside the call to a constructor. Change it the following and it should work:

```
MusicGUI gooey = new MusicGUI(files);
```

You can only pass a reference to an object or a variable or literal as a parameter within a method or a constructor.

---

### Update

I'm updating some code here. Try to see if this works for you.

Here's the `StreamAudio` class:

```
public class StreamAudio {

    private List<File> files;

    public StreamAudio() {
        files = new ArrayList<File>();

        File folder = new File("/Users/ananth/Music/Songs");
        File[] allFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3");
            }
        });

        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            for (File file : allFiles) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    files.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(files);
    }

    public List<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamAudio streamAudio = new StreamAudio();
        MusicGUI gooey = new MusicGUI(streamAudio.getFiles());
        gooey.showUI();
    }

}
```

And here's the `MusicGUI` class:

```
public class MusicGUI {

    private TextArea textArea;
    private List<File> files;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Player player;

    private int index = -1;

    public MusicGUI(List<File> t) {
        files = t;
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        JButton next = new JButton("Next");
        textArea = new TextArea("", 15, 80, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Now Playing: ");

        // panel properties
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        // play button
        JButton play = new JButton("Play");

        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent jh) {
                String path = files.get(++index).getPath();
                ///////////////////////// MUSIC CODE ///////////////////////////////

                System.out.println("path: " + path);
                File song = new File(path);

                String name = song.getName();
                name.replace(".mp3", "");

                label.setText("Now Playing " + name);
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(song);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                    Player player = new Player(bis);
                    try {
                        player.play();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
        });

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent jk) {
                try {
                    player.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                if(index==files.size()){
                    index = -1;
                }
                String path = files.get(++index).getPath();
                System.out.println("path: " + path);
                File song = new File(path);

                String name = song.getName();
                name.replace(".mp3", "");
                label.setText("Now Playing " + name);
            }
        });

        panel.add(play);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(next);
    }

    public void showUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrostMusic");
        // frame properties
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(650, 450);
        frame.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i do that and run the program. it immediately comes to an end. its really late and im getting tired, i should of seen that lol, im so dumb. but why is it not doing anything now? forgive me for being a newb

Comment: I did try to run your program, and I too saw that nothing happened. Plus the `Player` class was missing. I just put some dummy code to compile your classes successfully.

Comment: what do you think it would be?

Comment: player is not a clas. player comes from the jlayer import. it plays audio files. you have to get the jar and add it to the libraries.

Comment: I updated my answer to add some code. This fires up the GUI (gooey :) ). But I haven't used Jlayer. Just a dummy class for simulation. So, you might get some compile warnings/errors. Hopefully, you should be able to sort them out quickly.